# Automatic PHP Notification with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have bought a Notification theme for my website and I am trying to get some data from the website to notify the people who are logged in.

AJAX/jQuery/Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cron/notify.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $.smallBox( 
        {
            var id = data[5],
            title: "New Ticket",
            content: "A new ticket has been created. Ticket ID: <strong>" +id+"</strong><p><h6>This will close in 4 Seconds.</h6>",
            color: "#000",
            timeout: 4000
        });
    }
    setInterval(get_new, 1000);
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    mysql_connect(REDACTED FOR SECURITY) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(REDACTED FOR SECURITY) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE DATE_ADD(submitDate, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) < CURTIME()  AND currentStatus='Open'");
    $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo json_encode($array);
    ?>
```

I am getting no issues or errors.

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cron/notify.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#botSimple1").click(function(){
            $.smallBox( 
        {
            title: "New Ticket",
            content: "A new ticket has been created. Ticket ID: <strong>" +data[5]+"</strong><p><h6>This will close in 4 Seconds.</h6>",
            color: "#000",
            timeout: 4000
        });
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

This is the new script, no errors from JavaScript, but the notification boxes are actually button ones. Can they be modified?

Comment: the problem is you are not looping the all values come from db. After that you are sending values in `json` format but not parsing at receiving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging AJAX can be a pain.  You have to have a clear understanding 
how the parts fit together:

1. with $.ajax you send the ajax request to the server
2. cron/notify.php on the server produces some data and sends it back
3. the function you defined for "success" is called with the data
4. it calles smallBox to display the data -

so there's several places where something could be going wrong

- in your browsers developer tools / firebug: check in the "network" tab if the requests are actually sent
- in your browser: try opening the URL of your backend directly - in this case "cron/notify.php" - does it show the data you expect?
- in your javascript code: you are only handling "success" in your javascript, try adding functions for error
- in your browsers console: try starting a $.smallBox( ) - does it actually display anything
- in your  javascript code: before you send your data to the smallBox: dump it to the console with console.log(data) to check if it has the expected value

See http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=196802787&siteSectionName=tools for a tutorial on how to use firebug to debug AJAX

Comment: Ok I have it working, but the data[4] via the var id = only pulls "2"